# Cannot access administrative share (c$) on a Windows 8 PC from Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, sharing, windows

I'm having an issue trying to access administrative shares on my Windows 8 PC from my MacBook Air running OSX 10.8.2.

Here is the process, errors and background info:

1. On the MacBook, Go menu > Connect to Server > Server Address:  smb://megaman/c$ > Connect
2. Connect as: Registered User > Name: Zach; Password: my password  [This is an admin account on the Windows 8 PC]
3. "There was a problem connecting to the server "megaman". You do not have permission to access this server.

Ok, fine....So as a sanity check, I make sure the administrative share (c$) exists on the Windows8 PC, and that the 'Zach' account is a member of the Administrators group. That all checks out. Next, I create a new share of the 'c' drive on the Windows 8 PC and in the share settings, only give the user account 'Zach' Full permissions.

I run back through steps 1-3, but this time I just enter 'smb://megaman' for the server address. I get the 'Select the volumes you want to mount on "megaman"' dialog box on the MacBook and 'c' is listed as a share. I select 'c' and click OK. The share mounts without error.

I've also tried mounting the c$ share via command line and get a "Permission denied" error. I've tried disabling the firewall, but this doesn't make any difference. I've tried deleting and recreating the administrative share, and also creating a new admin account on the Windows 8 PC, but none of those make any difference either.

Perhaps it's a setting in local security policy on the Windows 8 PC? I can't say for sure, but my guess is that this issue began with Windows 8, since I used to be able to access the c$ share when my PC ran Windows 7.

Comment: Love the "Megaman" name for your server!

Comment: I just had this issue with my Windows 7 PC

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Administrative shares have been disabled in Windows Vista and later versions of Windows [for security reasons](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951016).

According to [Microsoft Support Knowledge Base article 947232](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947232), you can do one of the following:

1. Create your own shares with the appropriate permissions (recommended);
2. Run the Microsoft Fix It to perform an automatic workaround; or
3. Add to the Registry subkey `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` a DWORD (32-bit) Value `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` entry with the value data of `1`.

Comment: Yep, you nailed it. Read up on the KB article and creating the LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy entry does let me access the administrative shares. Thanks.